# AVAssetWriter invalid URL for writing

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl

I'm getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] invalid parameter not satisfying: [outputURL isFileURL]'
```

On this line:

```
AVAssetWriter * assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:videoURL
                                                        fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                           error: &movieError];
```

Where videoURL logs as:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/A032EEA6-C83D-49DA-B118-E4E4B9F41C7F/Documents/videoForSegmentNumber1.mp4
```

the line before this is called.

I've also tested against isFileURL myself and its returning NO. What is required to be a valid fileURL?

Comment: Are you using `+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path` NSURL method? If you could show us how you create your URL that'd be great :)

Comment: I'm using URLWithString:. It looks like that was the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path
```

instead of

```
+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
```